# A few issues with sketchpad's background colour and size

Tags: javascript, css

I am building a simple sketchpad, a small project from The Odin Project and so far I am having a few issues that I can't figure it out how to solve.

First, I am using a button to change size of the board and works fine but when I change the size of the board the click just won't work, I can't draw and the `getPointerMessage();` won't execute.

Second, I want the user to change the background colour of the board but it will collapse with what the clear button does, so if I press the red background button, draw and then press the clear button again it will change the colour of every div since I am iterating through the variable `square`, I have tried with the .remove() method but it won't work, any ideas?

**Edit: Haven't solved the problem yet and I also have seen a really odd behaviour when changing size, every time you change the size and set the same size once and once again the board will shrink, sometimes mouse won't click, sometimes will click.**

Thank you.

```js
let color = 'black';
let click = true;
function populatedBoard(size) {
    let board = document.querySelector('.board');
    board.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${size}, 1fr)`;
    board.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${size}, 1fr)`;
    let divSize = size * size;
    for (let i = 0; i < divSize; i++) {
        let fill = document.createElement('div');
        fill.className = 'sq';
        fill.addEventListener('mouseover', paintBoard);
        board.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', fill);
    }
    board.addEventListener('click', () => {
        click = !click
        getPointerMessage();
    });
    changeBg();
}

function paintBoard() {
    if (click) {
        this.style.backgroundColor = color;
        if (color == 'random') this.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(${Math.random() * 360}, 100%, 50%)`;
    }
}

function changeColor(input) {
 color = input;
}

function clearBoard() {
    let board = document.querySelector('.board');
    let squares = document.querySelectorAll('.sq');
    squares.forEach((sq) => sq.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(134, 101, 212)');
}

function getPointerMessage() {
    let pointerMessage = document.querySelector('.pointer-message');
    if (click) {
        pointerMessage.textContent = 'You are allowed to paint ✅';
    } else {
        pointerMessage.textContent = 'You are not allowed to paint ';
    }
}

function getBoardSize() {
    let errorMessage = document.querySelector('.error-message');
    let input = prompt('Select a board size');
    if (input <= 0) {
        errorMessage.textContent = 'Negative numbers not allowed'
    } else if (input > 100) {
        errorMessage.textContent = 'Set a number between 1 and 64!';
    } else {
        errorMessage.textContent = '';
        return input;
    }
}

function getButtonSize() {
    let sizeButton = document.querySelector('.select-size');
    sizeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let size = getBoardSize();
        populatedBoard(size);
    })
}

function changeBg() {
    let boardBackground = document.querySelector('.change-bg');
        let board = document.querySelector('.board');
        boardBackground.addEventListener('click', () => {
            board.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        })
}

getButtonSize();
populatedBoard(32);
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.board {
    display: grid;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: rgb(134, 101, 212);
    border: 3px dashed rebeccapurple;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.error-message {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: red;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sketchpad.css">
    <script src="sketchpad.js" defer></script>
    <title>Etch a Sketch!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Stekchpad!</h1>
    <button class="btn btn-primary select-size">Select size</button>
    <span class="error-message"></span>
    <span class="pointer-message">You are allowed to paint ✅</span>
    <div class="board"></div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="btn btn-dark" onclick="changeColor('black')">Black</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="changeColor('red')">Red</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="changeColor('random')">Random</button>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="clearBoard()">Clear</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger change-bg">Red background</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```